# Vitamin D vs vitamin D3

Tags: diet, vitamins

What is the difference between vitamin D and vitamin D3 ?

In terms of complement and effects on the metabolism / body ?

Answer (score 1):

D3, also called cholecalciferol, is just one form of the actual vitamin D.  D3 is the preferred form of vitamin D for the body that is why when you buy it at pharmacy, it is usually D3.  When vitamin D is formed by the body in the presence of sunlight, that is also D3.

Comment: While this is a decent answer, we encourage not answering off topic questions.